# How to get data in python from arduino using SIM800L wirelessly

Tags: python, arduino-uno, gsm, gsmcomm

I'm working on a project where I use a SIM800L wireless module to transfer data from an Arduino to Python. I'm not sure how I can do that or what credentials I'll need. What would be the Python code and what would be the procedures. I scoured the internet but came up empty-handed. Please, could someone assist me in finishing this job.

I hope to transfer every parameter from the Arduino code to Python so that I can handle data in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Two separate problems. Programming the Arduino with Python, and using WiFi on the Arduino. An Arduino can't run a normal Python interpreter, but specially crafted versions called [MicroPython](https://micropython.org/) can run on some boards.

If you're looking to run Python on a host computer, then you'll need something to communicate to the Arduino: take a look at how [Firmata](https://github.com/firmata/protocol) and [PyFirmata](https://github.com/tino/pyFirmata) do just that. Good tutorial to get started here:  https://realpython.com/arduino-python/#hello-world-with-arduino-and-python.

Finally, to use PyFirmata over Wifi, you'll of course need an Arduino with a Wifi module. See the [`StandardFirmataWifi`](https://github.com/firmata/arduino/blob/main/examples/StandardFirmataWiFi/StandardFirmataWiFi.ino) example sketch to show you how Firmata can accept intstructions over a TCP connection.

Comment: He asked about GSM, not wifi.